# CURL CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER in conflict with CURLOPT_HEADER

Tags: php, curl, php-curl

When I use both parameters in my curl:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true) and
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE)
```

I receive an empty data back.

Any idea why?

When I remove `CURLOPT_HEADER`, I have my response where I can convert to array. Only problem here is that the header isn't provided.

When I remove `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER`, I get the full string (header and body). The only problem here is that it prints directly and I'm not able to convert it to an array.

Someone who has an idea?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://localhost/api/upload.php');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
```

Comment: Under you can find my response.  <br/>

But it gives me an empty data back. 
It works perfect when I delete curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE) but then I don't see my header. <br/>

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url.$location.$folder);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
      'Content-Type:application/json',
      'Authorization: Bearer '.$token, 
      'Accept: application/json',
      'ContinuePath: '.$ContinuePath ));
$response = curl_exec($ch);